# Where can I download the source code to the GNU C++ Standard Library?

Tags: c++, stl, gnu

I downloaded the GNU Standard C Library (glibc) source code at http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/. Where can I find a similar download for their C++ Library?

I have googled around a bit and cannot seem to find it.

The only reason I need it is I want to see how it is implemented. So please don't give me links to binaries or to just the header files because it is the implementation source files that I am looking for.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/libstdc++/

Comment: Most of the C++ standard library implementation *is* "just the header files"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's in the `libstdc++-v3` directory in the [`g++` (`gcc-c++`) sources.](https://gcc.gnu.org/git.html)

Comment: How can I download that though, without having to download each file individually?

Comment: Ok I figured out how to access the svn repository to download that same directory.

Comment: Now it is under github: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3

Answer (score 4):

**GCC mirror sites：**
https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html
Looking for what you want.